# Rails: Update only some attributes of an entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization

I'm new to Rails and i want to know if there is possibility to update some attribute an entity without the classic **find,modify **then** save**.

because it's take 2 request to databe, it's not optimal

Let's say we have an user and we want to change her username:

the normal way

```
u = User.find(id)
u.username = 'newUsername'
u.save
```

the way i'm looking for:

```
User.**XXXX**(id:Y,username: 'newUsername')
```

Ps: **Update** method need all attribue  else-where this method update none given attribute to '**nil**'

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update).

You can call .update on the class with the parameters you want to update.

```
# Updates one record
Person.update(15, user_name: "Samuel", group: "expert")

# Updates multiple records
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)
```

Comment: The problem with the update method if you don't specify an attribute, the others will be saved in NULL